# Create a 2nd column based on the maximum date By Month in 1st column

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, group-by, max

I would like to create a 2nd column based on the maximum date by month in 1st column, but I'm having trouble identifying the maximum date by month in the 1st column (first step below).

I'm trying to do a `groupby` but im getting a `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`.

I believe the steps are:

1. Within the `datadate` column, identify the maximum date by month. Eg.
   1/29/1993, 2/11/1993, 3/29/1993, etc.
2. For the `datadate` row that equals the maximum date by month: in a new column called `last_day_in_month`, put the maximum
   possible date: Eg. 1/31/1993, 2/28/1993, 3/31/1993, etc. For all the other rows where `datadate` row != maximum date by month, put
   `False`.

Sample Data and Ideal Output:

```
{'tic': {0: 'SPY', 1: 'SPY', 2: 'SPY', 3: 'SPY', 4: 'SPY', 5: 'SPY', 6: 'SPY', 7: 'SPY', 8: 'SPY', 9: 'SPY'}, 'cusip': {0: '78462F103', 1: '78462F103', 2: '78462F103', 3: '78462F103', 4: '78462F103', 5: '78462F103', 6: '78462F103', 7: '78462F103', 8: '78462F103', 9: '78462F103'}, 'datadate': {0: '1993-01-29', 1: '1993-02-01', 2: '1993-02-02', 3: '1993-02-03', 4: '1993-02-04', 5: '1993-02-05', 6: '1993-02-08', 7: '1993-02-09', 8: '1993-02-10', 9: '1993-02-11'}, 'prccd': {0: 43.938, 1: 44.25, 2: 44.34375, 3: 44.8125, 4: 45.0, 5: 44.96875, 6: 44.96875, 7: 44.65625, 8: 44.71875, 9: 44.9375}, 'next_year': {0: '1994-01-25', 1: '1994-01-26', 2: '1994-01-27', 3: '1994-01-28', 4: '1994-01-31', 5: '1994-02-01', 6: '1994-02-02', 7: '1994-02-03', 8: '1994-02-04', 9: '1994-02-07'}, 'next_year_px': {0: 47.1875, 1: 47.3125, 2: 47.75, 3: 47.875, 4: 48.21875, 5: 47.96875, 6: 48.28125, 7: 48.0625, 8: 46.96875, 9: 47.1875}, 'one_yr_chg': {0: 0.073956484136738, 1: 0.0692090395480226, 2: 0.076814658210007, 3: 0.0683403068340306, 4: 0.0715277777777777, 5: 0.0667129951355107, 6: 0.0736622654621264, 7: 0.0762771168649405, 8: 0.050314465408805, 9: 0.0500695410292072}, 'daily_chg': {0: nan, 1: 0.0071009149255769, 2: 0.0021186440677967, 3: 0.0105708245243127, 4: 0.0041841004184099, 5: -0.0006944444444444, 6: 0.0, 7: -0.0069492703266157, 8: 0.0013995801259623, 9: 0.004891684136967}, 'last_day_in_month': {0: '1993-01-31', 1: 'False', 2: 'False', 3: 'False', 4: 'False', 5: 'False', 6: 'False', 7: 'False', 8: 'False', 9: '1993-02-28'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check group by month and `idxmax` for maximum days. Check `to_period` and `to_timestamp` for last day of each month.

```
datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datadate)
max_day_indx = datetime.groupby(datetime.dt.month).idxmax()
df['last_day_in_month'] = False
df.loc[max_day_indx, 'last_day_in_month'] = datetime[max_day_indx].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp('M').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)

   tic      cusip    datadate     prccd   next_year  next_year_px  one_yr_chg  \
0  SPY  78462F103  1993-01-29  43.93800  1994-01-25      47.18750    0.073956   
1  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-01  44.25000  1994-01-26      47.31250    0.069209   
2  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-02  44.34375  1994-01-27      47.75000    0.076815   
3  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-03  44.81250  1994-01-28      47.87500    0.068340   
4  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-04  45.00000  1994-01-31      48.21875    0.071528   
5  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-05  44.96875  1994-02-01      47.96875    0.066713   
6  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-08  44.96875  1994-02-02      48.28125    0.073662   
7  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-09  44.65625  1994-02-03      48.06250    0.076277   
8  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-10  44.71875  1994-02-04      46.96875    0.050314   
9  SPY  78462F103  1993-02-11  44.93750  1994-02-07      47.18750    0.050070   

   daily_chg last_day_in_month  
0        NaN        1993-01-31  
1   0.007101             False  
2   0.002119             False  
3   0.010571             False  
4   0.004184             False  
5  -0.000694             False  
6   0.000000             False  
7  -0.006949             False  
8   0.001400             False  
9   0.004892        1993-02-28
```

Comment: Am getting strange results - it seems to only work for values that are greater than the year >2021, and leaves the last_day_in_month column as False for all months less than the year <2021. Is there a way to adjust this?